# Unexpected EOF while looking for matching ' " '

Tags: bash, shell-script, hadoop

I'm trying to configure hadoop using cygwin.. It is my first time to use unix environment but while configuring hadoop-env.sh i get the this EOF error

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# Set Hadoop-specific environment variables here.

# The only required environment variable is JAVA_HOME.  All others are
# optional.  When running a distributed configuration it is best to
# set JAVA_HOME in this file, so that it is correctly defined on
# remote nodes.

# The java implementation to use.
export JAVA_HOME=${"C:\Java\"}

# The jsvc implementation to use. Jsvc is required to run secure datanodes
# that bind to privileged ports to provide authentication of data transfer
# protocol.  Jsvc is not required if SASL is configured for authentication                 of
# data transfer protocol using non-privileged ports.
#export JSVC_HOME=${JSVC_HOME}

export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=${HADOOP_CONF_DIR:-"/etc/hadoop"}

# Extra Java CLASSPATH elements.  Automatically insert capacity-scheduler.
for f in $HADOOP_HOME/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar; do
  if [ "$HADOOP_CLASSPATH" ]; then
    export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$f
  else
    export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$f
  fi
done

# The maximum amount of heap to use, in MB. Default is 1000.
#export HADOOP_HEAPSIZE=
#export HADOOP_NAMENODE_INIT_HEAPSIZE=""

# Extra Java runtime options.  Empty by default.
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"

# Command specific options appended to HADOOP_OPTS when specified
export HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS="-        Dhadoop.security.logger=${HADOOP_SECURITY_LOGGER:-INFO,RFAS} -    Dhdfs.audit.logger=${HDFS_AUDIT_LOGGER:-INFO,NullAppender}     $HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS"
export HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS="-Dhadoop.security.logger=ERROR,RFAS     $HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS"

export HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS="-Dhadoop.security.logger=${HADOOP_SECURITY_LOGGER:-INFO,RFAS} -    Dhdfs.audit.logger=${HDFS_AUDIT_LOGGER:-INFO,NullAppender}     $HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS"

export HADOOP_NFS3_OPTS="$HADOOP_NFS3_OPTS"
export HADOOP_PORTMAP_OPTS="-Xmx512m $HADOOP_PORTMAP_OPTS"

# The following applies to multiple commands (fs, dfs, fsck, distcp etc)
export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-Xmx512m $HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS"
#HADOOP_JAVA_PLATFORM_OPTS="-XX:-UsePerfData $HADOOP_JAVA_PLATFORM_OPTS"

# On secure datanodes, user to run the datanode as after dropping     privileges.
# This **MUST** be uncommented to enable secure HDFS if using privileged     ports
# to provide authentication of data transfer protocol.  This **MUST NOT** be
# defined if SASL is configured for authentication of data transfer protocol
# using non-privileged ports.
export HADOOP_SECURE_DN_USER=${HADOOP_SECURE_DN_USER}

# Where log files are stored.  $HADOOP_HOME/logs by default.
#export HADOOP_LOG_DIR=${HADOOP_LOG_DIR}/$USER

# Where log files are stored in the secure data environment.
export HADOOP_SECURE_DN_LOG_DIR=${HADOOP_LOG_DIR}/${HADOOP_HDFS_USER}


# The directory where pid files are stored. /tmp by default.
# NOTE: this should be set to a directory that can only be written to by 
#       the user that will run the hadoop daemons.  Otherwise there is the
#       potential for a symlink attack.
export HADOOP_PID_DIR=${HADOOP_PID_DIR}
export HADOOP_SECURE_DN_PID_DIR=${HADOOP_PID_DIR}

# A string representing this instance of hadoop. $USER by default.
export HADOOP_IDENT_STRING=$USER
```

And here is the error

```
/home/mahmoud/hadoop-2.7.1/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh: line 62: unexpected EOF     while looking for matching `"'
/home/mahmoud/hadoop-2.7.1/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh: line 87: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Thanks for your reply..... I'm trying to set the Java home... i tried using \\ but it doesn't work any other suggestion please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quoting looks generally okay, but you probably are running into problems with this line:

```
export JAVA_HOME=${"C:\Java\"}
```

The first use of `"` is not escaped, while the second one is. The `'\'` character acts as an *escape* in shell scripts, changing the meaning of the following character. The shell cannot tell that you may have meant to supply a trailing backslash, e.g., in a Cygwin or MinGW port.  If you *did*, doubling each of the backslashes is the way to do this.

Something to check: if your runtime will translate forward slashes to back slashes, e.g., to appease an underlying Windows system.  If you can, that makes the script easier to work with.

Addressing a comment, in

```
export JAVA_HOME=${"C:\Java\"}
```

the `${` and `}` are not helpful.  You can do what is needed with just

```
export JAVA_HOME="C:\\Java\\"
```

The '${`and '}` delimit [*parameter expansion*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02).  You could in principle perform a substitution within the curly braces, e.g., for changing forward slashes to backward slashes:

```
FORWARD_HOME='C:/Java/'
export JAVA_HOME=${FORWARD_HOME//\//\\}
```

Further reading:

- [export JAVA_HOME with spaces in Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567191/export-java-home-with-spaces-in-cygwin)
- [How to set JAVA_HOME in cygwin](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.apache.mahout.user/11484)
- [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), in particular `${parameter/pattern/string}`
- [Replace forward slash with double backslash enclosed in double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379293/replace-forward-slash-with-double-backslash-enclosed-in-double-quotes)

Comment: Thanks for you reply.... but could you explain more

Comment: Are the `${` and `}` even necessary?

Comment: no - but OP could use that for substituting slashes versus backslashes (a different question), and dropping those would not fix the actual problem.